# Does the disc always return to the thrower?

Tags: tron

It seems like in Tron and Tron Legacy the identity discs always return to their thrower. Regardless of how many times they ricochet or which direction they travel.

Will the disc always return to the thrower (owner)?

Comment: It should be noted that there is no reason to assume that any real world physics should limit the behavior of the discs. It is a virtual environment.

Comment: `if disk_distance > too_far_for_my_liking: return disk`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they do so in both *[TRON (1982)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084827/)* and *[TRON: Legacy (2012)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1104001/)*. It's the same in every media I know about, the disc always return to its owner.

Video-game [Discs of TRON](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Discs_of_TRON) has a slight variation since you got 3 discs and they shatter when they hit the enemy. The discs appear to somehow return to the player's possession as you could always throw 3 of them no matter how many shatter.

In [TRON 2.0](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/TRON_2.0), it plays an important part in gameplay. Since the disc also serves as blocker, you are defenceless when you throw your disc and you have to wait for its return before throwing it again. But this changes when you get other weapons and upgrades. If I remember correctly, you where even able to change the standard disc's trajectory after it was thrown, or even recall it, which imply some kind of remote control.

Also, at some point in [TRON: Uprising, Season 1 Episode 3: The Renegade, Part 2](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/TRON%3a_Uprising_S1E3_The_Renegade,_Part_2), Beck and Cutler throw theirs disk but mix them on catching, they immediately switch them back when they notice theirs mistake. This imply the disk don't automatically return to the thrower if they are intercepted.

Comment: I'd qualify that slightly... The disk returns to a thrower... You can lose a disk if it gets taken from you, as we see in Tron Legacy.

Comment: Yes, but I think the question was referring to combat, rather then theft.

Comment: And in [Tron: Uprising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron:_Uprising), on rare occasions, discs would curve in mid-air with no ricochets.  And it wasn't a boomerang effect, in one particular instance it swerved through a bunch of cross-beams.  (This series takes place between _Tron_ and _Tron: Legacy_)

Comment: So, when does the disc decide to return to the owner? After its velocity drops below a certain level? After a certain number of ricochet hits? When its path is going to be a certain distance from its owner? A certain length of time?

Comment: Like John O said I would think in terms of programs reacting to each other, not physics.